# Rewrite php function in joomla to also show jerror 404 when item not published

Tags: php, function, joomla

There is a function been built up to show a product whose listing is done

```
    function loadProduct($vid)
     {
    $database =& JFactory::getDBO();
    global $Itemid; 
    $sql = "Select *, (select product_name from #__usedtoy_products where product_id=v.v_prod_id) as product_name 
          from #__usedtoy_variants AS v Where v.v_status='1' and v.v_id = '".$vid."'";
    $database->setQuery($sql);
    $rows = $database->loadObjectList();
    return $rows[0];
     }
```

Now what is the best way to write this function where the function can also have

```
    if v.v_status='0'
    JError::raiseError(404, "Message");
```

Comment: Do you really want if v.v_status='0' or do you want when 0 rows are returned?  Those are two different things.

Comment: Hello Elin, Thanks for replying. Here v_status is basically the publishing status of the product. So if the product is unpublished or unavilable with v.v_status='0' - the function should return J404 error - this is the objective. can you help in it

Comment: But you are returning a list, not one item (although I'm not sure why you are returning a list if you are only going to take the first one anyway). Anyway, I think what you are say is that if  is_null($rows[0]) redirect to a 404 and I'd do it in the normal way ... except personally I'd not return a 404 there, since that is going to give control to your error page rather than your normal site with all its details and styling etc.  Why not just return a message that says the "product is not available"? That's going to look a lot better and be more flexible.